# Can I make `rm` interactive only when using globbing? (in either bash or zsh or both)

Tags: bash, zsh, wildcards, rm

Whenever I `rm` multiple items at once with shell globbing and there's even the slightest possibility that the pattern expands to more than I expect it to, I always try to remember to add `-i`, but (of course) I could forget and accidentally blow away something useful.  Some people try to solve this problem with an alias, such as `alias rm='rm -i'` but I hate the idea of making rm *always* interactive, because then I'll get into the habit of using `-f` all the time, which will obviously defeat the whole purpose.

What I'd like to do is make `rm` only use `-i` when I use globbing, and for `-f` of course to override `-i`, so I can still blow away whole directories with the usual `rm -rf junk`.

Therefore `rm *blah*` would really be `rm -i *blah*` but `rm blah` would work exactly as typed.

In case there's a difference in how this might be accomplished in different shells, I will chose an answer that supplies methods for both bash *and* zsh over answers that only cover one or the other.

---

**Note**: I'm not actually convinced this is necessarily a good idea; I'm just asking if it is possible.  If you think this is a stupid idea, I would be very happy to hear the reasoning behind your opinion, but ***please don't post such comments in the answer field***.  Real answers either tell me how to do this or explain that/why it is not possible (or possibly offer an alternative method to getting a similar result).  But if you want to tell me why this is dumb, please post as a comment.  I'll upvote well-reasoned comments even if I disagree with the conclusion.

Comment: A few suggestions: with GNU utilities, `rm -I` is like `-i` that only triggers when more than three files or `-r` is passed.  In `bash`, use `Ctrl-x *` keyboard shortcut to expand the glob and inspect it yourself.

Comment: With bash, I believe the answer is "no". With zsh, you might be able to take advantage of `noglob` by e.g., aliasing rm to `noglob my-rm`, and then having my-rm be a script that checks for a glob, expands it, and passes -i or not. Not sure, don't know zsh.

Comment: @derobert: you certainly *sound* like you know zsh pretty well.

Comment: @iconoclast Nope, not zsh, just Google. Oddly, I found that when trying to find how to do it in bash. :-P

Comment: If you want something that looks like rm but actually works different, I should write a script (or alias/function/function key) called `myrm` and let that script do what wonderful things you like.

Comment: I feel like you can do this with zle. Like how I made `.` default to `~/.zshrc` when no arguments are passed: https://github.com/raxod502/radian/blob/3abcf512049eef3b178efba5960c056ac12be7e6/.zshrc#L109

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not easy. The problem is that when you do:

```
rm -- *.txt
```

rm just sees the list of files, not the globbing pattern which has already been expanded by the shell.

What you could do is (zsh):

```
alias rm='noglob rm'
```

This tells zsh that patterns should not be expanded when calling rm. Then you can redefine rm as a function that does the expansion itself and adds the "-i" if need be something like:

```
'rm'() {
  [[ "$*" = *[*[?]* ]] && set -- -i "$@"
  command rm $~@
}
```

The problem with that approach though is that this new "rm" doesn't see the difference between

```
rm *
```

and

```
rm '*'
```

To remove the file called `*`, you'd have to write it:

```
rm [*]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this wasn't the case when you asked this question 9 years ago, but what you want here is currently the default with zsh. It'll notice when you're about to run `rm` with `*` and prompt you before running it:

```
$ rm *
zsh: sure you want to delete all 10 files in /foo/bar [yn]?
```

There's also these relevant shell options:

> RM_STAR_SILENT (-H)
>
> Do not query the user before executing `rm *` or `rm path/*`.
>
> RM_STAR_WAIT
>
> If querying the user before executing `rm  *`  or  `rm  path/*`, first  wait  ten seconds and ignore anything typed in that time. This avoids the problem of reflexively answering  `yes`  to  the query  when  one  didn't really mean it.  The wait and query can always be avoided by expanding the `*` in ZLE (with tab).

Comment: It was certainly the case 9 years ago, and even 30 years ago with the first release of `zsh` 1990, but that only covers `rm *` or `rm path/*`, not the  OP's `rm *blah*`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's true. Still, it seemed odd that no one mentioned this, so I thought I'd add it. It's the closest thing to the request and it avoids the pitfall you mentioned in your answer from back then. Quite possibly, it might be simple to patch to change the glob detection for the prompt so it uses the glob parser, or at least extend it a bit so it works with `*blah*`.

Answer (score -1):

Works in bash, probably in other shells.  Place in your `.bashrc`

```
function rm() { 
  while test "${1:0:1}" = "-"; do 
    shift
  done
  if test $# -eq 1; then 
    command rm "$1"
  else 
    command rm -i "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: You can use `command rm` to avoid hard-coding `PATH`.  Also, the approach of checking argument count is a bit unreliable, as `rm` can take options.

Comment: The "$1" should be quoted, or this will fail if the single file passed contains a space. @jw013 - You can also escape the command, eg `\rm`

Comment: @jordanm You are correct about the need to quote `$1` with double quotes, but wrong about the command escaping.  Quoting only suppresses aliases, *NOT* function look-up.  This answer is suggesting a function, not an alias.

Comment: At least the old edit was functional - the new edit discards user command line options, which is probably not the correct thing to do.

Comment: @jw013 - I was not aware that only worked for alias lookups, not functions. Thanks for the information.

Comment: So does this work now? @jw013

Comment: @Pureferret no, don't use this answer.