# Preventing deletion of system/shell aliased folders

Tags: bash, rm

Is there a way to prevent deletion of system/shell aliased folders? I want these commands to fail. My shell is bash.

Such as:

```
$rm -rf .
$rm -rf ..
$rm -rf ~
$rm -rf *
```

Comment: `.` and `..` are real links. They are not special shell expansions.

Comment: `tcsh` and `zsh` (enabled by default in `zsh`, you need `set rmstar` in `tcsh`), do issue a confirmation prompt when you do a `rm *` or `rm xxx/*`.

Comment: Most implementations of `rm` will refuse to remove `.` and `..` (exception is `zsh`'s `rm` builtin (zsh globs never expand `.` nor `..`)).

Comment: Related: [Can I make `rm` interactive only when using globbing? (in either bash or zsh or both)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46535/22565)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `~` and `*` are expanded by the shell *before* passing the arguments to `rm`.

The only way to do it is to define a function named `rm` that parses the arguments before invoking `command rm ...`

I would not recommend it. When you get lazy, you get in trouble when you sit at some other computer without your self-protections. I used to `alias rm="rm -i"` before that bit me.

Comment: `alias rm="rm -I"` is more permissive than `-i`, I use this. I think these kind of aliases are necessary to prevent these mistakes, its not wise to write commands you know rely on this behaviour though.

Comment: If you define a function, that function will see the result of the expansion (`/home/glenn`, not `~`, the list of files, not `*`)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is an answer to this, but one thing I do in my .bashrc is to set `GLOBIGNORE=.:..`, this stops glob expansions from matching `.` and `..`. It also effectively enables `dotglob` which might not be what you want (`GLOBIGNORE=.:..:.*` stops this). I find this useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of `bash`:

```
typetext() {
  perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph";
    ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV' "$@"
}
checkrm() {
  local re='\<rm\>.*[[:blank:]]([.*~]|\.\.)([[:blank:]]|$)'
  if [[ $READLINE_LINE =~ $re ]]; then
    printf > /dev/tty "Are you sure? "
    read -n1 k
    echo
    if [[ $k != [yY] ]]; then
      READLINE_LINE=
      return
    fi
  fi
  typetext $'\n'
}  <> /dev/tty >&0
bind -x '"\C-m": checkrm'
```

Basically, upon pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>, our `checkrm` function is invoked.

It looks in the currently entered command line (`$READLINE_LINE` for which you need bash 4.3 or newer) for a `rm` word (also matches `/bin/rm`, but not in `rmdir`) followed by a `*`, `.`, `~` or `..` argument.

If it matches, it prompts the user for confirmation. If confirmed, a newline character is inserted in tty input buffer for the command to be accepted (both CR and LF are bound to *accept line*, we're only wrapping CR); if not, the current buffer is emptied.

Note that with versions of `bash` prior to 4.4, there was a hitting a bug that caused readline to stop functioning properly when a job was suspended.

Comment: 1. Load the above into bash. Start `emacs -nw`. Suspend emacs `C-z` and type: no visible output. Go back to emacs `fg` and exit emacs. Back at the prompt, whatever you type is invisible.

Comment: 2. I have a hard time understanding `\<rm\>` - why not just `rm`? What are the `\<\>` and where are they documented? Tried [ERE docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) but cannot find an explanation.

Comment: Found it: regarding `\<\>`, it's a [GNU Extension](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions), matching empty string at beginning and end of word, respectively.

Comment: @grebneke, I can reproduce your _1_ above and it looks like a bug in `bash`. Binding an external command to `^M` (like `bind -x '"\C-m": /bin/true'`) is enough to trigger it (use Ctrl+J to accept the line as we do in our TIOCSTI ioctl).

Comment: @grebneke, it looks like that bug is fixed in 4.4.

Comment: @grebneke, technically, `\<\>` is more of a BSD extension (was already in `ex` in the late 70s). It never made it to POSIX basic regular expressions. But has been in GNU regexps for a while if not the beginning. bash is the GNU shell, but I think it uses the system's regex library for its regexps, so it may not work on non-GNU/BSD systems.